# How to draw an arc in tikz that matches 2 dots on the coordinate axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a coordinate axis to define a linear interpolation.

The result I expect is:

[image: expected result]

At the moment, I'm drawing it using:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[anchor=west] {x};
        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[anchor=east] {y};
        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (-0.2,0);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,-0.2);

        \draw[thick,dashed,blue] (1,0) -- (1,1);
        \draw[thick,dashed,blue] (0,1) -- (1,1) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](a){};

        \draw[thick,dashed,blue] (4,0) -- (4,4);
        \draw[thick,dashed,blue] (0,4) -- (4,4) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](b){};
        
        \draw[thick,dashed,green] (2,0) -- (2,2);
        \draw[thick,dashed,green] (0,2) -- (2,2) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](c){};

        \draw[thick,blue] (0.5,0.5) -- (4.5,4.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

With the result:

[image: actual result]

Obviously it's half finished, at the moment I'm not interested in placing the labels or "styling" it.

So, my question is:

How can I draw the red arc that acts as a parable? I could draw it by hand with `arc`, but it seems to me something very tedious to match the blue dots with the arc. Is there a way to indicate this coincidence?

Comment: You can try something like \draw (-1, .7) to[out=-10, in=200] (1, 1) to[out=20, in=250] (4, 4) to[out=70, in=270] (5, 7);.  Then you can modify the angles if you need something else.  Note that there is the condition `out angle +180 = previous in angle` to have a differentiable function.

Comment: First draw red curve, than blea straight line so that it intersect red curve,, by use of `intersections` libraries determine intersections coordinated, from those coordinates draw dashed lines to axis, where add nodes with `x_1`, `y-1` etc. On the end draw green dashed line ...

Comment: Can You add a sketch hand made?

Comment: Thanks @DanielN, I have finally used your command to solve it; if you take the time to write it as an answer I will give it to you as valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are waiting for Tikz-help, here is a [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) version for comparison.  As @Zarko mentioned in his comment, it is a bit easier to start with the parabola and define the line between two points on the parabola.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path xx, yy;
    xx = 5 left -- 200 right;
    yy = xx rotated 90;

    path parabola, line;
    parabola = (origin for x = 1 upto 20: -- (x, x * x) endfor)
        xscaled 10 yscaled 1/3 shifted (-10, 42);

    z1 = point 5 of parabola;
    z2 = point 17 of parabola;

    line = 1.2[z2, z1] -- 1.2[z1, z2];
    z3 = point 3/8 of line;

    drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 red);
    draw parabola;
    label.ulft("$y=f(x)$", point infinity of parabola);

    drawoptions(withcolor 1/4[1/2 blue, white]);
    draw line;
    label.rt("$y=r(x)$", point infinity of line);
    forsuffixes @=1,2:
        draw (x@, 0) -- z@ -- (0, y@) dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
        draw z@ withpen pencircle scaled 3;
        label.bot("$x_{" & decimal @ & "}$", (x@, 0)); 
        label.lft("$y_{" & decimal @ & "}$", (0, y@)); 
    endfor

    interim ahangle := 30;

    drawoptions(withcolor 1/4[1/2 green, white]);
    drawarrow (x3, 0) -- z3 shifted 2 down dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
    drawarrow z3 -- (0, y3) dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
    draw z3 withpen pencircle scaled 3;
    label.bot("$x$", (x3, 0));
    label.lft("$y$", (0, y3));

    drawoptions();
    drawarrow xx; label.rt("$x$", point 2 of xx);
    drawarrow yy; label.lft("$y$", point 1 of yy);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

You need to compile this with `lualatex`.